# binary tree to binary search tree

Tags: python, tree, binary-search

Today I had an interview where I was asked to solve "Given an binary tree, convert it to binary search tree in minimum time, space complexity".

I wrote this code, but got the feedback that complexity could be improved without using sort and without using external storage.

How to do it?

```
##code goes below##:

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def inorder(root,arr):
    if root is None:
        return
    inorder(root.left, arr)
    arr.append(root.data)
    inorder(root.right, arr)

def binary_to_bst(root, arr):
    if root is None:
        return
    binary_to_bst(root.left, arr)
    root.data = arr.pop(0)
    binary_to_bst(root.right, arr)

root = Node(4)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(1)
root.left.left = Node(5)
root.left.right  = Node(7)
root.right.left = Node(12)
arr = []
inorder(root,arr)
arr.sort()
binary_to_bst(root, arr)
```

Comment: You describe the task as "Given an binary tree, convert it to a binary search tree." Now, a *binary tree* is unsorted (in general), but a *binary search tree* is sorted, so this task can't be done any faster than sorting the keys, and sorting arbitrary keys takes \$Θ(n\log n)\$. So I wonder if perhaps you haven't quite described the problem fully?

Comment: I find `got the feedback that complexity could be improved without using sort and without using external storage` interesting in an interview context: that would require the interviewer to spot the oversight causing o(n log n) time, *and* to know *how* to do RB or AVL trees *without additional storage* (as well as that Python allows *object morphing* for the way I think possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that time complexity could be improved. An in-place approach is to flatten the tree into a list (the key is to reuse child pointers), and recreate the tree as BST. To flatten,

```
    def flatten(root):
        rightmost = get_rightmost(root)
        while root:
            rightmost.right = root.left
            rightmost = get_rightmost(root.left)
            root.left = None
            root = root.right
```

The time complexity of flattening is linear.

To recreate,

```
    def list_to_bst(root):
        cursor = root
        while cursor:
            next = cursor.right
            cursor.right = None
            root = insert(root, cursor)
            cursor = next
```

`insert` is a standard (or balanced, if you want to go fancy) BST insertion. `get_rightmost` is trivial.

There is no recursion, so the space complexity is constant. The time complexity is bounded by insertion, that is in a \$O(n\log n)\$ ballpark.

Comment: can we implement simple binary tree? if yes then how? is there any source code? because as I noticed that the tree goes to one side of the root(parent).

Answer (score 1):

`pop(0)` on a Python list is an \$O(n)\$ operation because it is really an array rather than a list, and all remaining elements are shifted back to fill the empty slot. Swapping `left` and `right` in your code would allow you to `pop()` from the end instead, which is \$O(1)\$.

Using `pop(0)` on all elements pushed the complexity of the whole operation to \$O(n ^ 2)\$.

Comment: `Swapping left and right in your code would allow you to pop()` as would using `arr.sort(reverse=True)`